# Does a POST method create a new entity, and return the id of that entity, in openapi 3.0.2?

Tags: api, swagger, openapi

I understand that a POST method in openapi 3.0.2 is supposed to create a new entity, and return the id of that entity. When I add an additional route to GET or DELETE that entity by ID, I get a 404 error. I don't quite know why that might be.

Here are my post and get methods:

```
/api/globalorderdays:
post:
  tags:
    - Setup Global Order Days
  summary: Allows user to add order days and holidays to multiple 
           sessions.
  requestBody:
    required: true
    description: put text here
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/GlobalOrderSetupInfo'
  responses:
    201:
      description: Created
    400:
      description: Bad request
    401:
      description: Unauthorized

/api/globalorderdays/{Id}:
get:
  tags:
    - Setup Global Order Days
  summary: put text here
  parameters:
    - in: path
      name: Id
      required: true
      description: put text here
      schema:
        type: integer
        example:
  responses:
    200:
      description: Success
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/GlobalOrderSetupInfo'
    400:
      description: Bad request
    401:
      description: Unauthorized

/api/globalorderdays/{Id}:
delete:
  tags:
    - Setup Global Order Days
  summary: Allows user to delete added order days
  parameters:
    - in: path
      name: Id
      required: true
      description: put text here
      schema:
        type: integer
        example:
  responses:
    204:
      description: Deleted
    400:
      description: Bad request
    401:
      description: Unauthorized
```

Here are the components:

```
GlobalOrderSetupInfo:
  description: 'Put Text Here'
  type: object
  properties:
    Id:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    AvailableHolidayList:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    SelectedOrderHolidays:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    SelectedHolidays:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    OrderDays:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    NoOrderDays:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    AllSessionList:
      uniqueItems: false
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/SessionInfoList'
    SessionIdString:
      type: string
      nullable: true

SessionInfoList:
  description: 'Put Text Here'
  type: object
  properties:
    Id:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    SessionID:
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    Name:
      type: string
      nullable: true
    Type:
      type: string
    GroupName:
      type: string
    IsChecked:
      type: boolean
      default: false
    SetupID:
      type: string
      nullable: true
```

I expect to be able to retrieve/delete the entity by Id, but I return 404 errors

Comment: Your server implementation is what handles the creation/deletion and other business logic. How is your server implemented? Does it actually implement GET and DELETE for the `/api/globalorderdays/{Id}` endpoint?

Comment: Right now I am running the SwaggerHub API Auto Mocking.

Comment: @Helen I also tried to use Postman and used it's mock server and I can successfully post still but still cannot GET or DELETE. I return 404 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with your spec.

1. The `/api/globalorderdays/{Id}` path is repeated several times. This is not valid.

   ```yaml
   # Incorrect

   /api/globalorderdays/{Id}:
     get:
       ...

   /api/globalorderdays/{Id}:
     delete:
       ...
   ```

   Instead, specify the path once and list all of its HTTP methods below it, like so:

   ```yaml
   /api/globalorderdays/{Id}:
     get:
       ...
     delete:
       ...
   ```
2. Parameter examples are missing the value:

   ```yaml
   schema:
     type: integer
     example:   # <-----
   ```

   A missing value in YAML is an equivalent of `null`, but `null` is not a valid example for an integer schema. Either add a proper integer example, such as `example: 1`, or remove the `example` keyword from those schemas.

Once these issues are fixed, the mocks for GET and DELETE will work properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I went ahead and fixed the errors you caught. I am still running into the same issue though. I get a successful 201 when I post, but when I go to retrieve or delete it I am still getting a 404 on postman and a 405 on the swagger editor. Do you think it has something to do with both my GlobalOrderSetupInfo component and SessionInfoList component having Id as a property?

Comment: How do the actual request and response look like when you get 404/405 errors?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question. The 405 just says "undocumented" and the 404 error message says "We were unable to find any matching requests for this method type and the mock path, '/api/globalorderdays/1', in your collection."

Comment: Delete the API Auto Mocking integration and then add it again to force update the mock. If this does not fix the issue, [contact SwaggerHub support](https://support.smartbear.com/message/?prod=SwaggerHub) to troubleshoot the issue with them.

Comment: that half way fixed it. So I can now successfully POST and DELETE. But when try the GET method it returns a 200 with just the example body and not what I actually tried to post

Comment: That's expected - it's [how the mock works](https://app.swaggerhub.com/help/integrations/api-auto-mocking). The mock returns static responses based on examples provided in the schema. To have any sort of business logic, you'll need to implement a server - e.g. generate a server stub, write code that would actually implement every operation, run the server, and then point the API docs to your live server.